# Node.JS/Meteor on multiple servers serving the same application

Tags: node.js, meteor

When coming to deploy Node.JS/Meteor for large scale application a single CPU will not be sufficient. We also would like to have it on multiple servers for redundancy.

What is the recommended setup for such deployment ? how does the load balancing works ? will this support the push data technology for cross servers clients (one client connects to server 1, 2nd client connects to server 2 and we would like an update in client one to be seen in client 2 and vice versa).

Thanks Roni.

Comment: Support for multiple machines per app, easy scalability and a lot of features related to it will be available in Galaxy, new deployment platform Meteor core team is working on at the moment

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you just need to use a proxy between them. The paid galaxy solution should help but details are scarce at the moment as the product isn't out yet.

You can't simply proxy (normally using nginx, etc) between two servers as each server will store the user's state (i.e their login state) during the DDP Session (the raw wire protocol meteor uses to transmit data).

There is one way you could do it at the moment. Get [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) and install a package called [meteor-cluster](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/cluster).

The package should help you relay data between instances and relay data between the instances via Redis. A youtube video also shows this and how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use [Hipache](https://github.com/dotcloud/hipache) to manage the load balancing. You can use multiple workers (backends) for one frontent, like so:

```
$ redis-cli rpush frontend:www.yourdomain.com http://address.of.server.2
$ redis-cli rpush frontend:www.yourdomain.com http://address.of.server.2
```

There is more information on how to do this in the git page I linked to above, there is a single config file to edit and the rest is done for you. You may also want to have a dedicated server for MongoDB.